# adding a matrix with appending using dlmwrite in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to write two different matrices in  a file. However, first matrix is just initial values=>  25*ones(10,10). Second matrix is also 10x10 matrix , and updating in every iteration.  My question is , first matrix will be on the beginning of the file, later on second matrix will be appending the end of the first matrix after each iteration and updating. I dont want to overwrite the second matrix everytime,  which is happening when i run these codes

My codes are like this:

```
if ss==5000;

dlmwrite('d:\Temp.txt',Tin*ones(10,10), ' ');
dlmwrite('d:\Temp.txt', Tnew,'-append','roffset', 1, 'delimiter', ' ');

ss=0
end
```

Could you help me on this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you don't want to overwrite it, it means you want to keep appending it, or just write it once at the last iteration?

Comment: I want to keep appending it for 2nd matrix. However, 1st matrix needs to be written only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a complete example that demonstrates what I think you want.
If the file doesn't exist, it creates it and puts your first matrix inside it. If it does exist, it appends subsequent data

```
filename = 'd:\Temp.txt';

for ss=1:25000

    if mod(ss,5000)==0

        %generate some data to write
        Tnew = rand(10,10);

        if ~exist(filename,'file')
            dlmwrite(filename,ones(10,10), ' ');
        end
        dlmwrite(filename, Tnew,'-append','roffset', 1, 'delimiter', ' ');

    end

end
```